# AFNetworking and singleton

Tags: ios, multithreading, singleton, afnetworking

probably my question will be stupid.

I've seen a lot of examples and tutorials for applications that using AFNetworking. 
Many of these use create a singleton Client for interaction with the REST server. 
For example:

```
@interface APIClient : AFHTTPClient

+ (APIClient *)sharedClient;

@end

@implementation APIClient

+ (APIClient *)sharedClient {
    static APIClient *sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedClient = [[APIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]];
    }); 

    return sharedClient;
}

@end
```

But, is it safe to have a singleton for this? If my application is multithreaded is convenient to have a singleton?

---

**EDIT**

In this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial) uses a class RestfulClass which is a singleton. 
It is also used a delegate to notify the result of the requests. 
Is used a delegate ..e this does not seem like the best choice if you are using a singleton, is correct this my thinking?

Suppose  that we have two classes: A and B 
Both use the singleton and so `sharedClient` method. A and B can set they self as delegate ... this is wrong because one overwrite the other...
All methods have no control for the thread safe, is this correct?

Comment: singleton are single instance that can be shared by many threads which is done by making sure object is  
properly synchronized across the threads like your methods have done. It's perfectly safe in Cocoa as network requests run asynchronously and support concurrent operations.

Comment: I modified my question. thx

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in way late here but I was looking for information on how to correctly setup a singleton around AFNetworking too. I found this blog post:
[singleton-afnetworking](http://blog.christophertao.com/singleton-afnetworking/)

Basically it states that AFNetworking can handle concurrent requests without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

So referencing on the tutorial you added, I would say you are correct where having a singleton instance of the web service would permit overriding of the delegate by other classes if they utilized the singleton at the same time.

To the tutorials point, I think their intent was to have completely separate web service classes so ideally you would never run into 2 classes using the singleton at the same time, but more or less the singleton would just be lazy loaded the next time the controller needed it.

I am going through this decision right now and I think if I do a single web service class I would just make it a class with static methods to make the requests (and with a block parameter to get the callback back in the controller) and which also maintains no state. I *think* it will be more clear on how to use it and ideally help avoid the confusion you stated in your question.